# How to use grid_propagate

Tags: python, tkinter

When i select the .db file, the label "realdatabaseframe" is making "the start_menu_frame"
disappear for some reason which i have no idea why...

It would be great if you could run it before helping me.

Thx for whoever helps me :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3 as s3


def ValueChecker(Value):
    """
        It's gonna return True if there is nothing, or it's gonna return False if there is anything.

    """
    if (Value.isspace() == True or Value == ""):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def pickafile():
    opnfile = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select a Sqlite Database", filetypes=(("DataBase Files", "*.db"),))
    if ValueChecker(opnfile) == False:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Selected DB", message=f"You've selected {opnfile}")
        nameofthefileLabel.config(text=opnfile.split("/")[-1])
        realdatabaseframe = LabelFrame(mainwindow, relief=FLAT, bg="blue")
        lbl = Label(realdatabaseframe, text="This is a test label",height=winfo, anchor="n")
        lbl.grid()
        realdatabaseframe.grid(row=0,column=1)  
        # realdatabaseframe.grid_propagate(True)
        # realdatabaseframe.place(relx=0.073)
    elif ValueChecker(opnfile) == True:
        messagebox.showwarning(title="File Warning", message="Please Select A file")

mainwindow = Tk()
mainwindow.title('Simple DB')
mainwindow.state("zoomed")

winfo = int(mainwindow.winfo_screenheight()) 


start_menu_frame = LabelFrame(mainwindow, relief=FLAT, borderwidth="5", height=winfo,bg="#d9d9d9", width="100")
nameofthefileLabel = Label(start_menu_frame,width="10",height="2", text="", bg=start_menu_frame.cget("bg"))

pickafilebutton = Button(
    start_menu_frame, 
    text="""Open Existing
Database""",
    fg='black',
    anchor="n",
    width="10",
    height="2",
    command=lambda:pickafile())

pickafilebutton.grid()
nameofthefileLabel.grid(row=1)
start_menu_frame.grid_propagate(False)
start_menu_frame.grid()
mainwindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because you have created a very tall label `lbl` with `height=winfo`.  Note that `height` for text label is in *lines*, so you have created a label with over 1000 lines which pushs `start_menu_frame` out of the window viewable area.  Try changing `height` to a smaller number like 10 and you will see the difference.

Comment: Using `grid_propagate` isn't usually recommended. If you give your interactive widgets (Entry, Text, etc) a good default size, and then make use of the options of `grid` or `pack`, tkinter will do a fantastic job of making sure everything fits and is visible.